# How to fix java in cmd?

Tags: angularjs, postgresql, spring-boot, solr

I have an application written in Spring Boot Postgre, Angular and Sol Apache. I launched the program on the Windows server and everything is ok. After some time (each time in a different way), the program stops responding, I go to the cmd and I see the requests do not work, but if you select and select the text in the cmd and hold the Ctrl key, then the request will be loaded one by one and eventually the program will work. If make the request again, then you have to go into the cmd and step by step load each line using Ctrl A and so on.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--h2 Database dependency for inMemory-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
        <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.22</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.12.Final</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Security-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>



server.port=8123
datasource.primary.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbAccounting
datasource.primary.username=dbAccounting
data.upload=uploads
solar.connection.url=http://localhost:8984/solr/company_record
datasource.primary.password=dbAccountingPassword
datasource.primary.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none




spring.thymeleaf.cache=false

spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/

#debug=true

logging.file=logs/book-keeping.log

spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=100MB

spring.http.multipart.maxRequestSize=100MB


flyway.enabled=true
flyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbAccounting
flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
flyway.user=dbAccounting
flyway.password=dbAccountingPassword
flyway.locations=db/migration

spring.datasource.connection-test-query="SELECT 1"
spring.datasource.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true

#logging.level.root=DEBUG
```

Comment: Run your applications as proper services, not by starting them in `cmd`. How you do that depends on your tech stack.

Comment: In the case of working as a service, this error also occurs